# Can I make a bot to scrape a Discord server once it''s logged in?

Tags: discord.py

Below is the beginning of a script to scrape a discord server with a bot.

How do I edit it to scrape from every channel in the server once I've logged in with the bot? (Perhaps by editing on_ready() instead of on_message()?)

Essentially, I want to scrape a channel without entering "_scan" into it. I would hard code the number of messages to scrape.

I give full credit for this to https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-gather-message-data-using-a-discord-bot-from-scratch-with-python-2fe239da3bcd, and more thoroughly, https://github.com/ThiagoFPMR/Scraper-Bot/blob/main/bot.py.

```
import os
import discord
import logging
import pandas as pd

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

client = discord.Client()
guild = discord.Guild

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game('_scan help'))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    elif message.content.startswith('_'):

        cmd = message.content.split()[0].replace("_","")
        if len(message.content.split()) > 1:
            parameters = message.content.split()[1:]

        # Bot Commands

        if cmd == 'scan':

            data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['content', 'time', 'author'])

            # Acquiring the channel via the bot command
            if len(message.channel_mentions) > 0:
                channel = message.channel_mentions[0]
            else:
                channel = message.channel

            ...
```

Comment: Adding API calls on the `on_ready` event is generally a bad idea as it gets triggered multiple times, not just once.